# Identifying USB keypad press in FreeBSD

Tags: x11, freebsd

I have an USB keypad and I would like to detect when the user has pressed those keys.

Right now if I check with `xev` the keycodes are the same. I.E., there is no difference between pressing the usb keypad or the keypad from the main keyboard.

Is there any way to intercept the USB Keypad in FreeBSD so I can use those keys for different tasks?